# Swift - move textField over keyboard upon showing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard

I need to move a textfield over the keyboard when it appears.

I am using the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

and then:

```
@objc func keyBoardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.commentViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
@objc func keyBoardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.commentViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

the problem is that it seems the keyboard height is not correct. In fact the bottom of the view is not aligned with the keyboard. There is a space between the view and the keyboard.

[image]

Honestly i don't understand what I am doing wrong...

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was the fact the bottom constraint was relative to the safe area.
So I have fixed it by adding this:

```
let safeAreaHeight = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
self.commentViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - safeAreaHeight
```

Here's the complete code:

```
 @objc func keyBoardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    let safeAreaHeight = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.commentViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - safeAreaHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```